# What are the inverses of this group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Consider the group $G= \mathbb{Z}^{*}_{7}$ under multiplication. What are the inverses?

I'm guessing that the identity element is 1, but then how can any $x \in G$ such that $x>1$ have an inverse?

Comment: Start with the definition: $G$ consists of residues mod $7$ that are represented by integers coprime to $7$.  Since $7$ is a prime, this makes things pretty easy to count, and the order of $G$ is six.  Now pick such a residue $x$ (other than one, for a challenge) and solve $x\cdot w \pmod{7}$.

Comment: Just solve each case, if you are having trouble. $2\cdot 4 = 1$, $3\cdot 5=1$, $6\cdot 6=1$, $1\cdot 1=1$.

Comment: For instance, the inverse of $2\in G$ is $4$, because $2\cdot 4 = 1 \pmod 7$.

Answer (score 2):

The point is you're working modulo 7, so you need, for all $x<7$, to find a $y$ such that $xy\equiv1\mod7$. $\mathbb{Z}_7^\ast=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. So here goes:

\begin{gather*}
1\cdot1=1; \\
2\cdot4=8\equiv1\mod7; \\
3\cdot5=15\equiv1\mod7; \\
6\cdot6=36\equiv1\mod7
\end{gather*}

Summarizing:

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{Element} & \text{inverse} \\
1 & 1 \\
2 & 4 \\
3 & 5 \\
4 & 2 \\
5 & 3 \\
6 & 6
\end{matrix}$$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with $\mathbb{Z}_{7}^{*}$ you only need to consider $x = 1,2,3,4,5,6$. For each of these $x$ you need to find another $x$ in the same set which when multiplied together yields $1$ mod($7$). For instance, $2\cdot 4 = 8 \equiv 1$ mod($7$). Once you have found one inverse, you have also found another one. Consider the case $2 \cdot 4 = 4 \cdot 2 \equiv 1$ mod($7$) which means that $4$ is the inverse of $2$, and $2$ is the inverse of $4$.

It's not really that difficult to look for inverses in such a small group as $\mathbb{Z}_{7}^{*}$, but in larger groups it gets harder. I would recommend you look into the Extended Euclidean Algorithm which is used to find inverses.

Comment: Actually, 0 should _not_ be considered, since we are in $\mathbb{Z}_7^\ast$, the star taking the 0 away.

Comment: Of course, my bad.